# Site page as a Mobile view

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer

I want to make a page that functions as the mobile view of our SP2010.
It has to be **clean** and **clear of all the MS (SP) code** to keep it w3c standard, is there any way to do something like this?
My case is to build a news mobile site with a view of the latest news items, selected from a database, but not really into SP and/or designer yet.

*('cause the mobile view built in in SP isn't our best solution for a mobile view (big company), we've thought of an option to create a site page as mobile view.)*

If you look at the really simple and easy example in php below, how do I get this in sharepoint?

```
<!doctype ...
<html><body>
<?php
//database connection, init and SELECT * FROM news
foreach ($item in $news) {
  echo "<div>{$item}</div>";
}
//close db
?>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For mobile devices to not be delivered the OOTB mobile view in SharePoint, you will need to first turn off the mobile view. Easy way to do this is by modifying your compat.browser file for the given web application.

Now for the mobile page itself, you can create a custom page, then link it to it's own master page. Are you using a collaboration site or a publishing site? With collaboration this is not too difficult, but for a publishing page, this can be much more difficult as publishing pages always use the custom master page.

Comment: thnx for your comment but we're not allowed to use the sharepoint mobile view.
how should i do it with collaboration site?